# single speed freewheel Shimano SF MX 30 vs Shimano SF-1200

Tags: freewheel, single-speed, sprocket

What is the difference between:
single speed freewheel Shimano **SF MX 30** and Shimano **SF-1200** ?

Why those freewheels donesn't appear on shimano website?

P.S. From the pictures it's clear that the removal tools are different.

[image: SF-1200]
[image: SF-MX30]

Answer (score 4):

The removal tool is the main difference. The one on the right is a more widely used fitting, and [this](https://www.parktool.com/product/freewheel-remover-fr-6?category=Cassette%20%26%20Freewheel)  is the tool you would want.The design on the left is more hassle to remove, so most companies use the other style now. Regarding your other question about freewheels, this MX 30 is a fine component, but the White Industries freewheels have a cartridge bearing and the ratchet has more points of engagement and is easier to service, etc. Well worth the money for the lifespan of a component like this.

Comment: "White" freewheel costs 100 - 125$ ?!.... Instead of 15-30 for Shimano...

Answer (score 1):

Googling for "specs shimano sf-mx30"  leads to a lot of hits from bike resellers, but none from shimano.com which confirms your findings.

The sf-1200 seems to be 16 tooth only, but the sf-mx30 is available in 16/17/18 tooth options.

Both are for 1/8" chain and both fit a standard freewheel mount of 1.370x24 tpi.

I suspect the main differences come down to tolerances and build quality.  The black mx30 has far less of a "china-BSO" appearance than the 1200, and various reviews suggest that the mx30 is more reliable.   You should search those out and compare yourself.

Though ultimately, what you get depends on availability.... if it is not in stock you can't have it and will have to settle or wait.

Comment: @Crigie, It seems me from few shops specs, that SF-1200 is for **1/8** chain and SF-MX30 is for **3/32** chain. Does it meaningful?

Comment: @MichaelD I didn't mention 3/32 because there was no obvious consistency in the results.  Most sites said 1/8" and only one said the mx30 was for both widths.  It's certainly possible.  The only info on shimano.com is that the mx30 tool is Y12009150
TL-FW45 and the sf-1200 tool is Y1200904T   TL-FW40

Comment: Which ever style you go for, don't forget to put ample grease on he hub threads before mounting it.

Comment: FWIW I found references to both freewheels in this [2021 Parts Catalogue](https://na.s-tec.shimano.com/s3_assets/filelibrary/Catalogs/2021_ORIGINAL_PARTS_Catalog.pdf) (p.67) and the online version of the [Technical Service Instructions leaflet (EN)](https://si.shimano.com/en/pdfs/si/0104A/SI-0104A-001-00-Eng.pdf) for the SF-MX30 (I got the same in paper with the freewheel with additional languages). I haven't searched for the SF-1200 specifically, you may find something at [https://si.shimano.com/](https://si.shimano.com/).